# IMA integration linker error when building in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, interstitial, ads, xcode9.1

I have integrated the google's IMA(Interstitial Media Ads) via cocoapods and add to my view controller as

```
- (void)requestAds {
    // Create an ad display container for ad rendering.
    IMAAdDisplayContainer *adDisplayContainer =
    [[IMAAdDisplayContainer alloc] initWithAdContainer:self.videoView companionSlots:nil];

    // Create an ad request with our ad tag, display container, and optional user context.
    IMAAdsRequest *request = [[IMAAdsRequest alloc] initWithAdTagUrl:kTestAppAdTagUrl3
                                                  adDisplayContainer:adDisplayContainer
                                                     contentPlayhead:nil
                                                         userContext:nil];
    [self.adsLoader requestAdsWithRequest:request];
}
```

Also added delegates and added IMAAdsLoaderDelegate, IMAAdsManagerDelegate in header but when I build, I am getting this error

> "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMAAdsRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RadioPlayerVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMAAdDisplayContainer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RadioPlayerVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMAAdsRenderingSettings", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RadioPlayerVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMAAdsLoader", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RadioPlayerVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)"

But when I added the framework in embedded binaries, I could build it but when I archive apple rejects the build stating

> "Invalid Segment Alignment - The app binary at
>   'xxx.app/Frameworks/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds'
>   does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with
>   the latest Xcode version."

I did not get a solution from google support so please help to fix it...

Comment: re run install pods after updating it

Comment: Please refer this link. https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-ios/releases

Comment: @swapnilpatel I have referred that link and integrated correctly and when the above error occurs,I searched the web and told to add the framework in embedded binaries but when I archive and build  apple rejects because the framework adds some invalid binary architectures to the app ....

Comment: Also I had   'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' integrated and working well..Does that conflict with   'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK' ??